# JSF error message not displayed

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

Am trying to render and error message if the current user doesn't have sufficient previliges

```
<h:form id="distribution">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <h:messages errorStyle="color:red" infoStyle="color:blue" globalOnly="true" />
                    <rich:panel style="width:560px;">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Owners list"></h:outputText>
                        </f:facet>
                        <rich:pickList value="#{BomDistributor.selectedOwners}"
                            sourceCaption="Available Owners" targetCaption="Selected Owners"
                            listWidth="165px" listHeight="100px" orderable="true"
                            required="true" requiredMessage="Please select owner">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{BomDistributor.availableOwners}"
                                var="capital" />

                        </rich:pickList>

                    </rich:panel>
                </h:panelGrid>

            </h:form>
```

and this is the bean , am calling it @ the bean constructor

```
public ScrubbingDistribution() {

this.loading = false;
this.now = Calendar.getInstance();
this.currentUser = (UserJTO) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("currentUser") ;

if(currentUser.getGroupJTO().getGroupId()!=1){          
        System.out.println("Not Allowed");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,  new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Not Allowed", "Only Admins can upload jobs"));
}
```

}
but am getting this at the console

```
INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=null[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(Not Allowed), detail=(Only Admins can upload jobs)]
```

what am doing wrong ?

Comment: Where do you instanciate the bean, where is it used and what scope does it have?

Comment: the bean is initialized when I click a link  and scope it's ViewScoped